# XMLHttpRequest() on a local .txt file is returning an empty responseText in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

For some reason my **XMLHttpRequest().responseText** is empty when trying to pull from a file contained in the same subdirectory.

I'm not checking for **XMLHttpRequest().status == 200**, because from what I have been able to discover during my searches, status will always be 0 if the requested file is local - an issue I had encountered minutes before when I was checking for **XMLHttpRequest().readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequest().status == 200**. This is due to not going through a webserver.

The file (data.txt) contains plain text, but the **responseText** is always returned empty, and I cannot figure out why. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

***UPDATE:***
Seems it works in Firefox, but not Chrome (with which I was using to test), or IE. These browser aren't putting data into responseText, so does anyone know why, or better, how to rectify it?

```
function loadData()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "data.txt", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4)
            useData(request.responseText);
    }
    request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried ´request.response´ instead of ´request.responseText´?

Comment: What do you see on the protocol? Fiddler/Firebug/Chrome dev tools will show what goes and comes on the wire.

Comment: I hadn't, Mark, so I tried. It was empty as well, however. But thanks for ruling it out.

Comment: I tried above code and it works for me fine may be you need to check Net tab in firebug

Comment: Pointy, the .txt file is sitting in the same directory as both the .js file and .htm file. Currently, the files are not on a server, but are in a folder on my desktop during development.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design to prevent javascript exploits shared as for example attachments in mail files (as something along the lines of domains doesn't exist for desktop application and there is just a single filesystem). For **development** you can disable this security feature in chrome by using the `--disable-web-security` flag, but in general you just have to accept that that's impossible.